# How does a newly connected client get old messages in AWS IOT

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot

Pretty simple scenario.

A message gets published on a topic (by a master device), to which no clients are currently subscribed.
 I am hoping messages published can have a custom expiry time.

So say within this expiry time, a client now connects to this topic.
How would this client receive the message published earlier?

What i am hoping to get as an answer, if it is possible and if so, what does AWS IOT provide to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi. Is the issue still unclear? I see that despite there being correct answers, none has been accepted?

Comment: The simple reason being, it's been 2.5 years since i asked this question, and since then have moved away from working on AWS. So now i have no idea, which answer is correct. :)
But i will just go ahead and pick the first answer. 
Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, above answer of @sanket has been true, with one change as follows:

Right now, AWS IoT supports MQTT persistent sessions. Please see following relevant snippet from AWS.

"Persistent sessions store subscription information and pending Quality of Service (QoS) 1 messages in case your devices become disconnected. When a device reconnects, its persistent session resumes and its subscriptions are automatically reinstated. Also, any stored messages are delivered."

Moreover, "Persistent sessions have a default expiry period of one hour. The expiry period begins when the message broker detects that a client disconnects (MQTT disconnect or timeout)."

Reference - [How does a newly connected client get old messages in AWS IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757327/how-does-a-newly-connected-client-get-old-messages-in-aws-iot)

Answer (score 1):

**With Any Standard MQTT Broker**

You should connect the client with the broker using **clean_session flag as False** so that after this the broker will maintain your state with itself.

Refer this:- https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/

[This document will fulfill your all queries.](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-clean-sessions-example/)

**NOTE:**

As per standard MQTT spec, above-mentioned rules should be followed by MQTT broker but AWS-IoT broker does not follow this.

AWS-IoT message broker does not support persistent sessions (connections made with the cleanSession flag set to false). The AWS IoT message broker assumes all sessions are clean sessions and messages are not stored across sessions. If an MQTT client attempts to connect to the AWS IoT message broker with the cleanSession set to false, the client will be disconnected.

**Possible Solution:**

AWS-IoT provides something similar to cleansession flag using DeviceShaddow functionality. 
[AWS Device Shadows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html)

Comment: How would this client receive the message published earlier? I was of the opinion that would be possible using the "retained" flag to true. and i also know that AWS IoT does not support retained messages.

Comment: Also i have gone over the net looking for Device shadow examples and tutorials, but i don't seem to find anything on Programmatic Device shadow creation and usage

Comment: Have you gone through https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/device-shadows-part-1-basics/. I have mostly worked on other MQTT broker which support clean-session flag functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The IOT Core Message Broker supports [Persistent session expiry period](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/01/aws-iot-core-now-enables-customers-to-store-messages-for-disconnected-devices/). [By default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#message-broker-limits) the messages associated with the session will be stored for **1 hour** in case of session disconnects:

> The duration for which the message broker stores an MQTT persistent session. The expiry period begins when the message broker detects the session has become disconnected. After the expiry period has elapsed, the message broker terminates the session and discards any associated queued messages. You can adjust this to a value from **1 hour to 7 days** by using the standard limit increase process.